# Unable to Run the batch file which contains the linux command(CD) in Java

Tags: javascript, java, linux

I need to run the batch (.bat ) file which contains cd command in that to go the directory and fetch the file using Java but it is not executing CD command .

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;


public class BatchRun {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        try {
            Process p1 = runtime.exec("cmd /c start C:\\Users\\543543\\Desktop\\Test.bat");
            InputStream is = p1.getInputStream();
            int i = 0;
            while( (i = is.read() ) != -1) {
                System.out.print((char)i);



            }
        } catch(IOException ioException) {
            System.out.println(ioException.getMessage() );
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Which error/issue do you get?

Comment: The Cd command is not working while calling the command by running the batch file which contains the command

Comment: How can you affirm that? Do you have error or exception after that? Can you post your .bat file?